# how to print data from table relation using with() funtion in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Here is the generated array from table relation:

```
{"id":1,"shelf":{"id":1,"name":"Computer Related","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor somet.","created_at":"2017-01-15 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-01-15 00:00:00","deleted_at":null},"book_no":"001","title":"Programming","author":"Rasmus Lerdorf","publisher":"Micheal Holmes","description":"The planning, scheduling, or performing of a program.","book_img":null,"no_of_books":20,"created_at":"2017-01-11 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-01-11 00:00:00","deleted_at":null}
```

Just want to know how can I get value of name from shelf array value.

Comment: where to you want to do it in javascript or mysql?

Comment: I want it to print using curly braces {{ }} in laravel blade.
Something like this: 
{{ $variable->field }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is in json format.so use `json_decode()` to convert into array.As below.

```
$json = '{"id":1,"shelf":{"id":1,"name":"Computer Related","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor somet.","created_at":"2017-01-15 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-01-15 00:00:00","deleted_at":null},"book_no":"001","title":"Programming","author":"Rasmus Lerdorf","publisher":"Micheal Holmes","description":"The planning, scheduling, or performing of a program.","book_img":null,"no_of_books":20,"created_at":"2017-01-11 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-01-11 00:00:00","deleted_at":null}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [shelf] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Computer Related [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor somet. [created_at] => 2017-01-15 00:00:00 [updated_at] => 2017-01-15 00:00:00 [deleted_at] => ) [book_no] => 001 [title] => Programming [author] => Rasmus Lerdorf [publisher] => Micheal Holmes [description] => The planning, scheduling, or performing of a program. [book_img] => [no_of_books] => 20 [created_at] => 2017-01-11 00:00:00 [updated_at] => 2017-01-11 00:00:00 [deleted_at] => )
```

Get value of name using `echo $array['shelf']['name'];` because your array is multidimensional.

Comment: yeah got it.. Thanks